# Query Azure SQL Database from local Azure Function using Managed Identities

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I want to query an Azure SQL Database from an Azure Function executing on my machine in debug using Managed Identities (i.e. the identity of my user connected to Visual Studio instead of providing UserId and Password in my connection string).

I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi) on Microsoft documentation so my Azure SQL Server has an AD user as admin which allowed me to give rights (db_datareader) to an Azure AD group I created with my Azure Function Identity and my user in it (and also my Function App deployed in Azure).

If I deploy and run in Azure my Azure Function, it is able to query my database and everything is working fine. But when I run my Azure Function locally, I have the following error :

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

The code of my function is the following:

```cs
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "test")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");


        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sqlConnectionString")))
        {
            connection.AccessToken = await (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net");
            log.LogInformation($"Access token : {connection.AccessToken}");
            try
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                var rows = await connection.QueryAsync<Test>("select top 10 * from TestTable");
                return new OkObjectResult(rows);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

        }
    }
```

The code retrieves a token correctly, the error occurs on line `await connection.OpenAsync()`.

If I open the database in Azure Data Studio with the same user than the one connected to Visual Studio (which is member of the AD group with the rights on the database), I can connect and query the database without any issue.

Is it a known issue or am I missing something here ?

Comment: Is the environment variable `sqlConnectionString` set when running locally?

Comment: Yes it is set in my `local.settings.json` file : 
"sqlConnectionString": "Server=tcp:myservername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydatabasename;",

Comment: I see. The only time I have seen this error earlier was when I specified the server name, but missed the database name. (because AAD logins have access at db level, not server level). But that error is pretty generic, so not sure what could be the cause.

Comment: It could be linked to this issue : https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/7022

Comment: Have a look at the tokens in both environments (Azure and local) through the https://jwt.ms and see whether they are different.

Comment: My tokens are similar, just with different identities. I noted however that the token I retrieve is not of the correct user, Visual Studio seems not to take the correct one...

Comment: Hijacking this question a bit... but is there any way to do this from VSCode (i'm working on a mac) can I set environment variables for my identityobjectid and tennantid or something like that?

Comment: I haven't tried but I think it should work using the azure cli. If you are connected to azure cli with your account I guess the managed identity can use that. Let us know if you succeed to make it work using that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying your specific scenario, I tested quite a few ways to try and get it to work locally. This didn't work, giving the same error message you're getting.

I discussed it with some people, when a possible solution came up. I tested it: it works!

The main issue in my case was that my subscription (and my user) is a Microsoft account (Outlook). Because of this, you need to specify the `tenantId` in the `GetAccessTokenAsync()` call.

Apparently, for managed identities you do not have to specify the `tenantId`. With a user, it's a good idea to explicitly specify it. In case of a personal MS account, specifying it is mandatory.

My code (sort of):

```
var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(QUERY, connection))
{
    connection.AccessToken = await tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/", "<YOUR_TENANT_ID>");

    await connection.OpenAsync();
    var result = (await command.ExecuteScalarAsync()).ToString();

    return new OkObjectResult(result);
}
```

This solution has been tested and works both when specifying the `tenantId` (or Directory ID, the tenant's GUID) and the 'onmicrosoft'-name (`xxx.onmicrosoft.com`).

Comment: Just tested it, it works fine. Thanks a lot !!!

Apparently not only the Microsoft account are concerned, I was using an account from another directory which is a guest on the directory of my database and I had the same issue.

I wanted to test with other accounts but for a reason I don't understand Visual Studio keeps using the same account as the managed identity whatever account I specify in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Is your local machine's IP Address white-listed?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure

[image: White-list IP]

Comment: Yes it is, I wouldn't be able to query from Azure Data Studio otherwise. But yes I checked that, if I use a connection string with secret and password my azure function works well.